# Getting the update row_count in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is a very simple example:

I have a table with two columns, `id` and `password`. I want to know when an update was done successfully, with success being defined as applied to an existing row.

PHP seems to only offer `mysql_affeted_rows()`, which doesn't differentiate between 0 rows affected, and 0 rows updated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php This is awkward because the return value is dependent on the state of rows at the time of the transaction. In Postgresql you can get it both ways, `UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL`, will return the amount of rows *updated* in `foo`; whereas, `UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL WHERE bar IS NOT NULL` will return the amount of rows *affected*, by limiting the update.

Don't bother suggesting a previous `SELECT`, or a PHP counter var, that assumes there is a row. I want to know of clever ways to get the Pg functionality, without redundant queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_affected_rows` will always return the number of rows updated by an `UPDATE`.

In other words, it will return the same number of rows for `UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL` as for `UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL WHERE bar IS NOT NULL` given the same starting data.

Or at least that's the way it's documented on the manual page you linked to, under the Return Values heading.

Comment: When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.

Comment: OMG Ponies:  Exactly, that's the documentation I was referring to.  Both queries have the effect of changing all non-null values in that column to null, so both should return the same number of affected rows.

Answer (score 1):

Does the mysqli function [num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) fits your needs ?

Comment: This would have been my answer.

Comment: I automatically assumed `mysqli_num_rows` has the same quirk as `mysql_num_rows`... that it only works for `SELECT` queries.